# What is the most pythonic way to check if an estimator in scikit-learn has a "fit" method?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What is the best pythonic way to check for the presence or absence of `fit` method in a *generic* machine learning model knowing its estimator?

Here is a portion of the code:

```
import os
import errno
from constants import (numerical_columns, categorics, names, ids)
from pycaret.regression import (setup, save_model, get_logs, compare_models, predict_model, plot_model, finalize_model, load_model)


def silentremove(filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            os.remove(filename)
        except OSError as e: # this would be "except OSError, e:" before Python 2.6
            if e.errno != errno.ENOENT: # errno.ENOENT = no such file or directory
                raise # re-raise exception if a different error occurred

def ml_modelling(all_data, train, test) -> None:

    for target_var in targets:
        numerical_features = [col for col in numerical_columns if col != target_var]

        X, y = train.loc[:, train.columns != target_var], train[target_var]
        s = setup(
            data=train,
            target=target_var,
            ignore_features = ['Series'],
            numeric_features=[el for el in numerical_features if el not in categorics],
            categorical_features = categorics,
            silent=True,
            log_experiment=True,)

        best_model = compare_models()   
        exp_logs = get_logs()
        save_model(best_model, 'best_model')
  
        # Making some plots  
        for id, name in zip(ids, names):
            target_name = f'plots/{target_var}/'+name+'.png'
            silentremove([name, target_name])
            try:
                best_model.fit(X, y)
                plot_model(str(best_model), plot=id, scale=6, save=True)
                os.rename(name, target_name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass # Code in case model does not have .fit() method
 
        final_best = finalize_model(best_model)
        loaded_model = load_model('best_model')
        prediction = predict_model(loaded_model, round=0,) 




##########################################################
def main() -> None:
    train, test = "some dataframes consisting of numerics and categoricals"
    ml_modelling(data, train, test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `'fit' in dir(Lasso)`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, yes! that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

"Ask forgiveness not permission" is generally considered Pythonic, so I suppose an approach like:

```
try:
    model.fit(Xdata, ydata)
except AttributeError:
    pass # Code in case model does not have .fit() method
```

Would be valid in many (but not all) use cases. Especially if a large portion of the given estimators would be from packages like sklearn, where almost all models would have a .fit method, because catching exception is quite slow. Though the "premature optimization is the root of all evil" idiom could be relevant here.

Realise that this would also catch potential AttributeErrors thrown within the excecution of the .fit() method, so it could theoretically make errors thrown in poorly implemented models harder to debug. If that is a problem in your use case, maybe it is better to ask for permission.

Comment: I am still receiving an error message saying after putting my code under try clause: ValueError: Estimator BayesianRidge(alpha_1=1e-06, alpha_2=1e-06, alpha_init=None,
              compute_score=False, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True,
              lambda_1=1e-06, lambda_2=1e-06, lambda_init=None, n_iter=300,  
              normalize=False, tol=0.001, verbose=False) does not have the required fit() method.

Comment: Could you provide more code and the exact Exception?

Comment: I see you modified the question with the new code exert. Is that (including indentation) how you have it in your code now?

Comment: yes, that's I have it in the code now.

Comment: Just wrote in a small version of the code

Comment: @Ash please edit in the full error traceback.